# Add Grand Total of LookupSet values

Tags: reporting-services, sum, lookup, reportbuilder

I am using this code to compute the individual values listed below:

- Item A   100
- Item B   200
- Item C   300
- GRAND TOTAL 600

  ```
  Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
  If items Is Nothing Then
  Return Nothing
  End If
  Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
  Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
  suma = 0
  ct = 0
  For Each item As Object In items
  suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
  ct += 1
  Next
  If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
  End Function
  ```

How can I compute the GRAND TOTAL value of 600?

Comment: I would think you would be able to use a similar expression as you are using for the individual ITEM totals - though with the LOOKUPSET criteria possible changed. What's your expression for the ITEM totals?

Comment: Here is the expression for the item totals 
        =code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!region2.Value, 
        Fields!region2.Value, Fields!actual_effort.Value, "OnMod"))                           I tried using the same formula for the grand total but got some huge wacked out number

Comment: Hmm...Are you doing any **filtering** in your **row group** that your individual totals are in? It sounds like it's filtering at the group level but unfiltered at the total level.

Comment: No filtering.  The rows ARE grouped but when I click on the item expression the Add Total option is greyed out.  I can add totals for non-expression items (data values) but not this one.

Comment: Huh - I can't think of any other things to check. Is the Region (Fields!region2.Value) the field with your ITEMs? I assume so since you're not filtering the **lookupset** for the ITEM.

Comment: Yes it is.  Funny this is the first time I haven't been able to find a solution for something. There has to be a way to do it using report code but i don't really know how to use that and I haven't found anything.  Thanks for your help.